# Life cycle of EBS and EC2 of Amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services

Does the life cycle of an EBS volume is coupled with the life cycle of an EC2 (meaning terminating an EC2 will terminate EBS volume as well)?

Answer (score 1):

No , terminating instance will not terminate EBS volume attached with it , thus you wont lose your DATA .

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the EBS volume was created. If it was created during the EC2 instance launch with the "Delete on Termination" flag set, it will be deleted, otherwise it will just remain as a unattached volume.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/block-device-mapping-concepts.html